# $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.')); not working cakephp 2.X

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, flash-message

I am trying to use Flash Component in cakephp2

I have declared the component

```
public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session', 'Flash');
```

Then trying to set Flash messages in controller:

```
$this->Flash->error('The cashpickup could not be saved. Please, try again.'); // To display error
$this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.')); // to display success
```

And in the view, I am using following code:

```
<?php echo $this->Flash->render(); ?>
```

Anyone? who can tell me the exact issue that why it is not working..

Comment: "not working" What does that mean? You need to provide a bit more infos here.

Comment: @mark It is not displaying Flash messages in the view

Answer (score 0):

In app/View/Elements/Flash/success.ctp

```xml
<div id="flash-<?php echo h($key) ?>" class="message-info success">
    <?php echo h($message) ?>: <?php echo h($params['name']) ?>, <?php echo h($params['email']) ?>.
</div>
```

as refer to https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/flash.html